# PostgreSQL Stored Procedure versioning

Tags: postgresql

I want do versioning stored procedure in Postgres. For example I try to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i INT) RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN i + 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- An example how to use the function (Returns: 11)
SELECT increment(10);
```

I read this article http://tech.valgog.com/2012/01/schema-based-versioning-and-deployment.html

Also documentation search_path:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-client.html

I do  `set search_path = v10_15, public;`

and I want to change return type:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(70)
```

but I get error:

> First remove function (DROP FUNCTION increment (integer)).

but I do not want to delete, I need a new version of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before set search_path you can create schema;
for example

> CREATE SCHEMA myschema;

Answer (score 0):

To rename a function, use `ALTER FUNCTION`. E.g.:

```
ALTER FUNCTION increment RENAME TO v10_15.increment;
```

---

If you were actually trying to create a new function in a new location:

If there's already a function by that name on the `search_path`, `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` will find it and try to replace the existing one.

Instead of relying on the `search_path` to define where to store things, be explicit and name the schema you want to create the function in:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION v10_15.increment(i INT) ...
```

Comment: Yes, but will have to change its name in product code on backend.
replaced `increment` on `v10_15.increment`

Comment: So you actually want to replace it, not create a new procedure? But you want to move the new one to a new schema?